# Optimize the SQL (40 minute run time)

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, optimization

<strike>**This is not an “add an index and check EXPLAIN” question.**</strike> I'm looking for a more optimized way to update/set a value in one table based on a JOIN query. This particular query is not a massive issue because it is a one-off item. I'm looking to improve my knowledge of how Postgres does things and better understand how to write queries.

This is running against two tables in Postgres 9.3.

SQL query:

```
UPDATE
    ordercontent t1
SET
    order_id = t2.id
FROM
    order t2
WHERE
    t1.pos_order_id = t2.pos_order_id AND
    t1.api_id = t2.api_id;
```

Table stats:

**ordercontent**

```
  rows  | api_id
--------+--------
 265435 |      2
 120561 |      3
 164288 |      4
```

Structure:

```
                                     Table "public.ordercontent"
    Column     |           Type           |                           Modifiers
---------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                  | not null default nextval('ordercontent_id_seq'::regclass)
 created       | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updated       | timestamp with time zone | not null
 api_id        | integer                  | not null
 obj_id        | character varying(255)   | not null
 raw_object    | text                     |
 order_id      | integer                  |
 item_id       | character varying(255)   | not null
 pos_order_id  | character varying(255)   | not null
 item_id       | integer                  |
 menuitem_id   | integer                  |
Indexes:
    "ordercontent_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ordercontent_api_id" btree (api_id)
    "ordercontent_item_id" btree (item_id)
    "ordercontent_pos_order_id" btree (pos_order_id)
    "ordercontent_menuitem_id" btree (menuitem_id)
    "ordercontent_obj_id" btree (obj_id)
    "ordercontent_order_id" btree (order_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "api_id_refs_apibase_ptr_id_9fe756a2" FOREIGN KEY (api_id) REFERENCES api(apibase_ptr_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "item_id_refs_id_bf9d5193" FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES lavu_menuitem(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "menuitem_id_refs_menuitembase_ptr_id_0da7969d" FOREIGN KEY (menuitem_id) REFERENCES menuitemforcedmodifier(menuitembase_ptr_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "order_id_refs_id_fd9de410" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "ordermodifier" CONSTRAINT "order_content_id_refs_id_fb05c9fc" FOREIGN KEY (order_content_id) REFERENCES ordercontent(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**order**

```
  rows  | api_id
--------+--------
 176808 |      2
  59207 |      3
 112849 |      4
```

Structure:

```
                                     Table "public.order"
    Column     |           Type           |                        Modifiers
---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                  | not null default nextval('order_id_seq'::regclass)
 created       | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updated       | timestamp with time zone | not null
 api_id        | integer                  | not null
 obj_id        | character varying(255)   | not null
 raw_object    | text                     |
 opened        | character varying(255)   |
 closed        | character varying(255)   |
 pos_order_id  | character varying(255)   | not null
 closed_on     | timestamp with time zone |
Indexes:
    "order_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "order_api_id_2190a0aad3aab788_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (api_id, obj_id)
    "order_api_id" btree (api_id)
    "order_closed_on" btree (closed_on)
    "order_pos_order_id" btree (lavu_order_id)
    "order_obj_id" btree (obj_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "api_id_refs_apibase_ptr_id_afc114a7" FOREIGN KEY (api_id) REFERENCES lavuapi(apibase_ptr_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "ordermodifier" CONSTRAINT "order_id_refs_id_92c3b747" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "ordercontent" CONSTRAINT "order_id_refs_id_fd9de410" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

EXPLAIN results:

```
Update on ordermodifier t1  (cost=83307.62..187654.96 rows=550908 width=330)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=83307.62..187654.96 rows=550908 width=330)
         Hash Cond: (((t2.pos_order_id)::text = (t1.pos_order_id)::text) AND (t2.api_id = t1.api_id))
         ->  Seq Scan on order t2  (cost=0.00..52685.08 rows=351359 width=22)
         ->  Hash  (cost=56134.41..56134.41 rows=590803 width=320)
               ->  Seq Scan on ordermodifier t1  (cost=0.00..56134.41 rows=590803 width=320)
```

---

### Background

I'm working with an external API provided by a POS system. That system returns orders by giving access to tables `order` and `ordercontent`. The former contains a specific order, the latter contains rows that correspond to line items in an order. I've synced all this data locally, but I need to recreate the foreign key relationships. Obviously this sync won't be terribly slow for updating a few hundred orders, but right now I'm syncing all orders for the past two years across multiple API's. Is there any way to improve the speed of this query?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @user1336827 `api_id` is a ForeignKey (should be indexed), and `pos_order_id` has an index on it.

Comment: 40 mins is not a long time for something you are only going to do once?

Comment: @JoshK: the table structure belongs in the question, not in the comments. It are not "just some details", it is the core of your data model, and the basis for the query planner. Also: `explain analyse` allows you to compare the estimated runtime with the actual runtime, and allows you to see *why* the optimiser chooses a *bad* plan.

Comment: @wildplasser I really didn't want to run a 40 minute query twice just to see *why* it was happening when, as I've stated and the comments on Denis's answer below point out it's a one-off thing.

Comment: @wildplasser I did add the table structure as well and a bit more of an explanation of *why* I'm asking this question (not to improve this query specifically but to understand Postgres better).

Comment: @JoshK: do you realize that you wasted _more_ than 40 minutes of everybody's time by asking an incomplete question ? BTW : `order` is a bad name for a table. It is a keyword in SQL.

Comment: @joop The table name is `pos_name_order`, I stripped that out when posting the question. And yes, I focused initially on just the query pattern itself without adding the table structure. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is not an “add an index and check EXPLAIN” question

Sorry, but… it is. If you don't have an index to make this work:

```
t1.pos_order_id = t2.pos_order_id AND
t1.api_id = t2.api_id
```

… then the query does a seq scan on both tables and a hash or merge join, or the wrong index scan (perhaps with a seq scan on the second table) and a hash or merge join, and the plan will basically, well, utterly suck.

You need an index on t1 and t2, both on `(pos_order_id, api_id)` or `(api_id, pos_order_id)`. Depending on whether you ever order by `pos_order_id, api_id` or the other way around, you might prefer the column you order by to the right — if neither, then either works.

At any rate, you still need to add an index, check explain, yada yada.

Regarding your comment:

> api_id is a ForeignKey (should be indexed), and pos_order_id has an index on it.

Not… `api_id` isn't necessarily indexed. Not on both tables anyway. The *referenced* table has a unique index on it; that yes. Not the referencing tables unless you've added it.

`pos_order_id`, while intuitively of lower cardinality than `api_id` based on the name, is evidently of little use here if your table has plethoras of rows that potentially match it. And even then, if the opposing table offers no index on the same, it is of little use in practice.

Regarding your (rather talkative) explain, since you've edited your question:

```
Hash Cond: (((t2.pos_order_id)::text = (t1.pos_order_id)::text) AND (t2.api_id = t1.api_id))
```

You're casting each and every row's column to text in there. That isn't just very, very, very wrong (on nearly a million rows, at that); it's crazy slow… You need to fix your type, too. (Casting won't be slow in your case, since you're going from varchar to text. But comparing ints will still be faster.)

As point out by David in the comments, the two indexes might be of little help given the cardinality. The stats in your current plan might be off. If not, you need to locate and update 550k or so rows, writing each one to disk (twice: delete old row, then insert new row) in the process. That's necessarily slow.

Another issue might be that you're storing things to disk. If it's still slow after changing your column type and adding the two indexes, [increase your work_mem](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server).

Comment: Hmmm, I forgot about having an index on those columns together. This query is only needed when updating and normally I'm not updating 500k records at once. I've added the EXPLAIN results above.

Comment: That's what I don't get. Your only doing this once so why care about 40 mins? At some point it's not the database but the hard drive and size of the db that is the bottleneck.

Comment: @JoshK: I've edited the answer (twice) based on your explain.

Comment: @AdamGent: ya, but in OP's case, there's something else at work, namely a typecast problem. An index on both tables (on either `pos_order_id` or `api_id`) can be helpful if the cardinality is low enough and/or if the stats show that they're clustered in the same area. On both combined is arguably better. But at the end of the day, Josh is currently casting nearly a million rows to text and doing a `char *` comparison over in C instead of simply comparing integers.

Comment: @Denis That's awesome stuff. The thing you pointed out that I overlooked is that it's casting things to text and then doing a comparison. These are foreign keys from the API and I can't know they will always be ints (the same API returns order_id in a form of `%d-%d`) which is why they are like that. Can I hint or improve the casting?

Comment: @Denis I've added the table structure to the original question as well. Your answer has been very insightful so far.

Comment: Fixing the data types would help, but it still looks like a hash join is going to be more efficient than an index-based lookup.

Comment: @Denis the OP added way more detail after my comment.

Comment: @AdamGent: ya, I edited my answer a bit more earlier today. I'm not so sure what I could possibly add to it at this point, though. As joop quipped in the comments, I may have spent more than 40 mins of my own time re-reading the question several times — and truth be told, I've much more important things to do with my time than trying to perfect a SO answer. ;-)

Comment: @Denis I appreciate the effort you put into the answer, it's definitely helped me understand better what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the ordercontent table and then updating it with the order.id seems to have two issues attached to it:

1. You already have a join between the tables, so adding order.id as well appears to be redundant.
2. If you really do need that value in that table, consider looking up the order.id as part of the table load, rather than as an additional step.

Updates are rather expensive as you not only have to find the value you need, but the row needs to be re-inserted into the table and the original removed (via vacuum). Eliminating the lookup of the value, or just the update, would be more efficient.

By the way, an index might not be more effective anyway -- in Oracle I'd hope to get a hash join for a query of that sort, and indexes are generally of limited help when you have to access an entire table.

Comment: I need to add it so the foreign key will work properly, because otherwise it would be a compound foreign key (api_id *and* order_id).

Comment: Why does that matter to you? Compound foreign keys are fine, and there's nothing more efficient than not taking a particular action at all. That aside, why not populate the value during the load if you're convinced that you need it?

Comment: Because that compound index isn't needed during daily operation and would slow down updates in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that this is not an “add an index and check EXPLAIN” question.  Since you seem to be updating most of the table, the hash join is probably the best way to do it.  If anything you have too many indexes, which all need to be maintained during this bulk update, and would better off dropping some, at least during the update.

EXPLAIN would be more useful it it were run with (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), and particularly if you turned on track_io_timing first.  Also, you say you want it faster, but how fast does it need to be?

The usual advice for bulk updates is to make sure checkpoints are not occurring too often.

I'd monitor the server (with top, for example) while the update is running and see if the server is IO bound or CPU bound.